# SQL - get total for each row GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm building a quiz application where each quiz can have multiple rounds. The rounds, participants & their answers are all being stored in their own tables and at the end of each round the results are shown. Currently, I'm getting the results using the SQL query below. This is calculating the number of questions answered, the correct answer count and the time taken and i'm grouping by the participants ID and Round Id and then ordering by the correct answer count and the time taken.

This works great for grouping the results by individual rounds but i would also like to get the total for each participant in the same query. I've tried using `WITH ROLLUP` at the end of `GROUP BY` but this ended up creating duplicate rows for both the `GROUP BY` clauses.

Is there another way I could get the total for each participant in the same the query or would this require a separate query?

```
SELECT quiz_participants.id,
        MAX(quiz_participants.name) as name,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, MIN(quiz_round_participants.started_at), MAX(quiz_round_participant_answers.created_at)) AS time_taken,
        COUNT(quiz_round_participant_answers.id) as answer_count,
        COUNT(answers.is_correct) as correct_count,
        quiz_round_participant_answers.round_id as round_id
FROM quiz_round_participant_answers
    INNER JOIN quiz_participants ON quiz_participants.id = quiz_round_participant_answers.participant_id
    INNER JOIN quiz_round_participants ON quiz_round_participants.participant_id = quiz_participants.id
    INNER JOIN quizzes ON quizzes.id = quiz_participants.quiz_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT id, is_correct
        FROM answers
        WHERE is_correct = 1
    ) answers ON answers.id = quiz_round_participant_answers.answer_id
WHERE quizzes.id = X
GROUP BY quiz_participants.id, quiz_round_participant_answers.round_id
ORDER BY correct_count DESC, time_taken ASC;
```

Comment: It should be a separate query.

Comment: I think you're right...